# Change a line of PHP via a text box

Tags: php, svg

I've got [this](https://github.com/kartsims/easysvg) functioning but as I understand it I need to edit the index.php file each time I would like to generate an SVG for a certain text. I'm not familiar with PHP, so sorry beforehand, but is there a way to create a text box so that whatever is typed into it then takes the spot of that particular line of code in the index.php file after hitting 'submit'? For example, after typing 'Hello there' into said text box line 23 of index.php would change to:

```
$svg->addText("Hello there");
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, see this documentation. http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php You also could pull it from a GET request, depends what your form is sending with.

Comment: I got this (http://codepad.org/KoNxekWx) to work, but I don't think this is using the technique both of you have recommended. Is there a better way or is this what you've suggested?

Comment: You're using the `$_POST` there. Is it not working? Make sure you are making a POST request otherwise that will be empty, you also may want to input default text for when the POST is empty.

Comment: It does in fact work, what I type into the text box and submit is then generated as an SVG. As I mentioned, I don't know PHP, so was just asking if this was in fact the method you both suggested, as I just kind of assembled some code from several sources to get it working.

Comment: Yes, that is what we are/were suggesting. I suggest one update though. `$typedtext = (!empty($_POST['new_text'])) ? $_POST['new_text'] : 'Default Text';` This way if the `POST is submitted with an empty input field or page loaded without submitting you still have an expected display. That's using ternary operator, a shorthand conditional. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you get started:

```
if(isset($_POST['new_text'])){

         $svg->addText($_POST['new_text']);

         // Rest of code here


}
```